# Shift values of multiple columns in data frame in r

Tags: r, shift

I have a data frame as below that some values are shifted for some columns:

```
 time    age    gender   day     ID
2018-01  47      male    mon     24
2018-02  NA       35     male    tue   45
2018-03  23     female   wed     45
2018-04  NA       61    female   mon   31
```

I want to shift column values where age is 'NA' and make them like other rows. Could you please tell me how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

For me it does not look like that you have already a `data.frame`. It looks more you have a text file which you want to read in. If this is the case you can read it in using `readLines`, then remove the `NA` with `gsub` and then you can create a `data.frame` using `read.table`.

```
#Read the lines as they are
x <- readLines(con=textConnection(" time    age    gender   day     ID
2018-01  47      male    mon     24
2018-02  NA       35     male    tue   45
2018-03  23     female   wed     45
2018-04  NA       61    female   mon   31"))

x  <- gsub("NA","",x) #Remove NA
x <- read.table(header=TRUE, text=x) #create data.frame
x
#     time age gender day ID
#1 2018-01  47   male mon 24
#2 2018-02  35   male tue 45
#3 2018-03  23 female wed 45
#4 2018-04  61 female mon 31
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's first generate your data.

```
data <- data.frame(
  time = c("2018-01", "2018-02", "2018-03", "2018-04"),
  age = c(47, NA_integer_, 23, NA_integer_),
  gender = c("male", 35, "female", 61),
  day = c("mon", "male", "wed", "female"),
  ID = c(24, "tue", 45, "mon"),
  null = c("", 45, "", 31),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

You could then solve your problem by using the `data.table` package by doing the following :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)

data[is.na(age), `:=`(
  age = as.double(gender),
  gender = day,
  day = ID,
  ID = null
)][, null:=NULL]

data[]
##        time age gender day ID
##  1: 2018-01  47   male mon 24
##  2: 2018-02  35   male tue 45
##  3: 2018-03  23 female wed 45
##  4: 2018-04  61 female mon 31
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using some for loops.
data is the data frame (already turned into an object)

```
for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {

 if (is.na(data$age[i])) {
  for (m in 3:6) { #starting by gender in column 3
   data[i, (m - 1)] <- data[i, m] #bring the value that lies in the next column to the preceding one
  }
 }
}

data <- data[, -ncol(data)] #to erase the remaining column
```